# Hapi server - how to modify the request body before it is handled by proxy handler

Tags: node.js, proxy, hapi.js

I have a  proxy handler

```
var options = {
    method: method,
    path: route,
    handler: {
      proxy: {
        ...
      }
    }
  };
  server.route(options);
```

How I can modify the request body before it is handled by the proxy ?

Answer (score 0):

As per their documentation.. You can change the uri.. But not the body.. Please see the docs for more info.. Else open a bug in hapijs [repo](https://github.com/hapijs/hapi/issues)

Comment: Would you mind sharing in their docs where this is. We're having a weird bug past few days where request body is not proxied. I've checked that it's being told to include the body.